# Write multiple strings to stdout and pipe them separately

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, pipe, stdout

Is it possible to pipe each string written to standard out to another command?

```
// file example.js
#!/usr/bin/env node
process.stdout.write('foo')
process.stdout.write('bar')
```

When I run `./example.js | wc -m` I get 6, the value of character length of both `foo` and `bar` together.

I'd like to get the values 3 and 3 separately. Do I have to do something special within my javascript file? or to the command?

Comment: The "pipe" in your example uses "stdout", which is a "stream".  Most programs (like "wc") read from the stream a line at a time.  You could easily write a program that reads a character at a time, then stop when it gets to white space.  BTW: [wc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) can count words (default), lines and or characters from stdout.

Comment: @paulsm4 what if my content is a file, that has spaces, what is a more reliable delimiter then line break or white space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**wc -m** counts the number of characters in its input. You can't make it separate/group by line (or any other grouping for that matter). This has nothing to do with your JS code.

If you'd like to get the type of counting by other means, it's actually not too difficult to do with node!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned your content may be a file which has spaces & lines, assuming you need character count of each file

```
//example.js    
#!/usr/bin/env node
process.stdout.write('foo')
process.stdout.write('~') // print any delimiter which is not part of your files content
process.stdout.write('bar')

//Split them using awk and count it as usual
./example.js | awk 'BEGIN { RS="~" } {print}' | wc -m
3
3

//or just using awk by removing spaces
./example.js | awk 'BEGIN { RS="~" } {gsub(" ", "", $0); print length}'
```

Hope this helps